# Alien romance series where a woman mates with a good alien who is a prince

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

So far what I remember about the first book is that evil aliens came to Earth and basically started killing everyone and everything. Shortly after the evil aliens arrival came some good aliens who wanted to kill all the bad aliens for attacking their planet.

One of the aliens is a young boy who goes to Earth without permission and is almost killed. He ends up being saved by a woman and they both end up being saved by his alien entourage when he gets rescued. She “mates”/“bonds” (I don't know what) to the main boss of the ship (a prince back on their planet, and the older brother of the boy she rescued) and is taken back to their home planet.

I read this as an ebook around 2 years ago. I don't remember the exact cover but I do know it had to be a shirtless guy or something with PDA. That’s honestly all I remember, but I do know this was a bigger series with at least 3-4 books. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: I read this as an ebook around 2 years ago. I don't remember the exact cover but I do know it had to be a shirtless guy or something with PDA. I know this 100% because I was lending my ipad to a family member at the time and I deleted any book with a weird cover!

Comment: Unfortunately, that describes a lot of books with similar covers on Amazon.

Comment: Trust me, I know! I've been looking for a while and I thought maybe posting here would jog someone's memory :)

Comment: https://travelbagmens.blogspot.com/2021/07/alien-romance-books-vk-amazoncom-alien.html for example.

Comment: If it helps, I went through all of the ones listed in that page but none of them were it :( Thank you though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is [Jakke](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56360327-jakke) by Hannah Davenport. It was originally released in 2016, then rereleased in 2020 so the rerelease fits with the time you remember reading it.

[image: Jakke 2016][image: Jakle 2020]

> The Tureis attacked Earth, killing most people in their first attacks. Sydney found a way to survive, carefully avoiding anything alien. When she found an injured Azziarin lying in a dark alley, she went against her every instinct and rescued him. After nursing him back to health, the Azziarin’s stormed her hideout, injuring her in the process.
>
> Unable to let the injured female remain lying on the ground, Takkeo ordered that she be brought back to their ship. She had helped him and he couldn’t leave her injured. How was he supposed to know that his older brother and Commander of the ship would experience the mating fever with her presence?
>
> Jakke had three consorts back home. Cassia had always thought that she would be his mate. He tried to avoid the earth female that brought forth his mating fever, but he ended up mated to her anyways. Now he had to explain things to her, his consorts, and his father, King Mallik. Could they all live together in unison? He sure hoped so.

The bad and good aliens are described as the *gray aliens* and the *white haired* aliens respectively.

Sydney finds the "good alien" boy, *Takkeo*, injured and rescues him:

> She’d only made it around the corner and halfway down the alley when she stopped short—there was a person sprawled out like a dead body in the alley.  She teetered. The last thing she wanted was to get involved, but how in good conscience could she walk away? What if he was alive and died because Sydney had been too scared to help?
>
> Crap!
>
> To make matters even more difficult, she knew he wasn’t Human. The white hair and dark skin marked him as possibly one of the good guys (such was yet to be determined). The only thing she knew about the aliens for certain was that the gray, pasty-skinned guys with red hair were definitely bad. Sydney would never help the gray guys, period.

Takkeo is rescued by his brother's officer *Sagge*. Sydney is injured in the attack and Takkeo insists she is rescued as well in return for helping him:

> “Takkeo, are you okay?”  Sagge asked as he knelt in front of the couch.
>
> “Yes.  Make sure the female is okay, and don’t let anyone hurt her!” Takkeo ordered.
>
> Sagge looked over his shoulder at the female lying in a heap on the floor.
>
> “No one touch the Human,” he ordered, although she was of no concern to them.  “And notify the Commander that we have Takkeo.”
>
> “She comes with us,” Takkeo said firmly.

Takkeo's elder brother *Jakke* then experiences *mating fever* as soon as he sees Sydney:

> Rykker wasn’t making him feel any better.  This was an impossible situation.  The Human female set his body on fire in the most primal way. Her exotic looks combined with that petite frame forced protective instincts to kick in. And he had only been in her presence a handful of minutes…what would happen over the next three weeks?

And the rest I'll leave to your imagination.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much John!!